# Namespace doesn't show in web service

Tags: namespaces, wsdl, biztalk

I have a WCF-Custom Transport Type Receive Location in BizTalk and the URI goes like https://productionenv.com/TPService/WcfService_TP_Orchestrations.svc.

The  Binding Type is wsHttpBinding and Security Mode is Transport. And in serviceMetadata the httpsGetEnabled is set True.

However when I open its corresponding web service in IE, the expected namespaces which I've created does not show like below:

```
<sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
 <wsp:Policy>
 <sp:TransportToken>
 <wsp:Policy>
  <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false" /> 
  </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:TransportToken>
 <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
 <wsp:Policy>
  <sp:Basic256 /> 
  </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
 <sp:Layout>
 <wsp:Policy>
  <sp:Strict /> 
  </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:Layout>
  </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:TransportBinding>
  <wsaw:UsingAddressing /> 
  </wsp:All>
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:import namespace="http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/2006/r2/wcf-adapter" location="https://productionenv.com/TPService/WcfService_TP_Orchestrations.svc?wsdl=wsdl0" />
```

Perhaps is there anything I missed in web.config part or the WCF-Custom Receive Loc itself that causes this issue?

Comment: Anyone has suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: If somebody please do know the resolution for this. I've been working on this problem for 2 weeks now.

Comment: If you browse to https://productionenv.com/TPService/WcfService_TP_Orchestrations.svc?wsdl=wsdl0 do you get the namespace you expect?